# Bokeh data is visualized only after script has ended

Tags: bokeh

My script is running through some sequential data generation steps that will finally produce a series of graphs. I want after each step to visualize the graphs that are available so far, but I only get a visualization after the script has completely finished.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                             
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure                                                      
import numpy as np                                                                             
                                                                                               
def plot_init(title):                                                                          
    global plot_circle                                                                         
    p = figure(title=title)                                                                    
    plot_circle = p.circle([],[])                                                              
    curdoc().add_root(p)                                                                       
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
def plot(data):                                                                                
    global plot_circle                                                                         
    plot_circle.data_source.stream(data)                                                       
    input("Continue...")                                                                       
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
plot_init("graph 1")
temp_x = np.random.rand(10)                                                                    
temp_y = np.random.rand(10)                                                                    
plot({'x': temp_x, 'y': temp_y})                                                               
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
plot_init("graph 2")                                                                           
temp_x = np.random.rand(10)                                                                    
temp_y = np.random.rand(10)                                                                    
plot({'x': temp_x, 'y': temp_y})
```

I start the bokeh server like this: `bokeh serve bokeh-test.py`

This is what happens:

1. I launch the server, console is waiting
2. I open the url in the browser, the script starts and "Continue..." is written on the console. **Nothing is displayed yet, the browser is still loading.**
3. I press a key, the scripts continues and "Continue..." is written on the console. **Nothing is displayed yet, the browser is still loading.**
4. I press a key, the script finishes. **Now the browser is displaying the two graphs that were generated.**

I'd expected after step 2. that the first graph would be displayed and after step 3 that the second graph would be added.

Most examples for 'streaming' data involve `add_periodic_callback()`, but I don't see how this would fit in my application, because I don't handle data that is streaming in from some external data source, I'm just generating data in the flow of my script.

How can I visualize my data with incremental results?

Best regards,
Vic

Comment: You need to actually modify / add things to `curdoc`. That is how the conduit through which Python <--> JS synchronization happens.

Comment: I'm using curdoc() to add the graphs. Also tried the approach suggestd by @tanel-joon using buttons to trigger callbacks, but somehow it looks likes the curdoc() calls only reach the client after the script has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that curdoc() does not seem to communicate to the client right away when it's called:

- if curdoc() is called in the main flow of the script, it is only effective when the script reaches the end
- if curdoc() is called in a callback, it is only effective when the callback returns

So I constructed my script such that the data generation flow is in a separate thread and a series of data handling callbacks is triggered using buttons, to do the drawing. The callbacks wait for the data to be generated using a semaphore and likewise the data generation waits for the user pressing the button using another semaphore.

Perhaps I made it overly complicated, but it works exactly as I want. I have a single flow of data generation and I can after each step inspect the graph and push a button to continue with the next data generation step.

Data is transferred from the data generator thread to the data handler callbacks via global variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure
from bokeh.models import Button
import threading
import numpy as np
import time

handler_lock = threading.Semaphore(0)  # handler waiting for data
generator_lock = threading.Semaphore(0)  # generator waiting for user pushing the button

# THIS IS A BOKEH CALLBACK:
def data_handler():
    global data
    global title
    global final
    # wait until data is ready
    print("Handler: waiting for data from generator")
    handler_lock.acquire()
    print("Handler: handling data from generator")
    # add new graph
    p = figure(title=title)
    plot_circle = p.circle([],[])
    curdoc().add_root(p)
    plot_circle.data_source.stream(data)
    # add the button for the user to trigger the callback that will draw the next graph
    if not final:
        button = Button(label="Continue data generation", button_type="success")
        button.on_click(data_handler)
        curdoc().add_root(button)
    # unlock the generator to continue generating data
    print("Handler: unlocking generator")
    generator_lock.release()
    # actual drawing is only done after the callback finishes!

# THIS RUNS IN A SEPARATE THREAD:
def data_generation():
    global data
    global title
    global final
    final = False

    # Data generation phase 1 (starts immediately!)
    print("Generator: starting data generation")
    temp_x = np.random.rand(10)
    temp_y = np.random.rand(10)
    #time.sleep(10)  # pretending data generation takes long
    print("Generator: Data generated, going to plot")
    data = {'x': temp_x, 'y': temp_y}
    title = "graph 1"
    # unlock the bokeh callback that is waiting for data
    print("Generator: Unlocking handler")
    handler_lock.release()

    # lock the generator until the callback is done
    print("Generator: waiting for handler to finish")
    generator_lock.acquire()
    print("Generator: continuing generating data")
    # Data generation phase 2
    print("Generator: starting data generation")
    temp_x = np.random.rand(10)
    temp_y = np.random.rand(10)
    #time.sleep(10)  # pretending data generation takes long
    print("Data generated, going to plot")
    data = {'x': temp_x, 'y': temp_y}
    title = "graph 2"
    final = True  # no button needed to continue
    # unlock the bokeh callback that is waiting for data
    print("Generator: unlocking handler")
    handler_lock.release()


# start data generation in a separate thread
t = threading.Thread(target=data_generation)
t.start()

# draw the start button
button = Button(label="Start handling data", button_type="success")
button.on_click(data_handler)
curdoc().add_root(button)

# main script finishes here, but the generator thread is still running and 
# iterative bokeh drawing is done in callbacks
```

Comment: Just to add some clarification based on some of the comments above. The entire "app script" (which might be a function passed to a `FunctionHandler` or an actual Python module run by a `ScriptHandler`) is properly considered a factory. It is the recipe for creating the document that is sent to the browser. But yes, very importantly: the *entire app code runs first* before anything is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be that you replace the input command - press any key - with a button press or something similar on your app. Basically after button click you execute rendering graph 1 or 2. With this approach bokeh will complete the rendering of the individual parts.

Comment: I tried adding a button when data is ready, and drawing the graph in its callback. It works, but the problem is the same: the buttons only visualize after the complete script has finished. Is this a limitation of using the `bokeh serve` way of launching the script?

Comment: What I mean is that you have the initial script - making the bokeh figures structure - and putting the whatever you need to run afterwards in the callback.

I'm running embedding bokeh content in flask. It's well described here http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html